# Gridster, how to auto remove columns that have been auto matically added with autogrow_cols?

Tags: javascript, gridster

we are using Gridster and it's nice and all. Works great, except for one thing.

We've enabled autogrow_cols which works well. Columns are added when needed, but they are not being removed when they are not being used. That is, when needed columns are added to the gridmap (for what I understand) but they are not being removed when they are not needed anymore. That means that when you start dragging a widget the container can be resized far beyond what is required. Which doesn't look very nice, especially when you've got something to the left of you widget layout (which in our case we have).

Does anyone know how we can make this work? I guess we have to hook into the 'dragstop' event. But can we then shrink the gridmap ourselves?

Can someone please shed a light on this?